# JQuery/Knockout Autocomplete script

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to find a resource in order to auto populate the location based on postcode provided.

e.g. When user types in 4 digits of post code, the auto complete kicks up and shows all the matched locations in format below. Postcode, Suburb, State e.g. 1234,abcSuburb,abcState.

I definately looks at jquery autocomplete at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. However it appears that list only contains exact searched items. My requirement is is to get additional item_details based on item searched.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Twitter's [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/).
They recently open sourced this and it's battle tested on twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

I've created a KO Combo, it coudl support this.

```
Live example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JD49k/6/

Repo
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox

Answer (score 0):

Use Ko.bindingHandlers for create custom function like
so easy to implement and use

```
<input id="ainput" class="form-control" data-bind="jqAuto: actualValue, jqAutoOnChange: autoChange, jqAutoQuery: autoQuery, jqAutoSourceLabel: 'Description', jqAutoSourceInputValue: 'Name', jqAutoSourceValue: 'Id'" />
```

here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/qkw2x0bd/29/) check out for working demo.